# How to implement new subscribe function? I am getting an error in my angular project that is indicating a depreciated function

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am a newby to angular. Looking for some help and clarification on this depreciated 'subscribe' function, thanks!

```
  onSignup(){
    console.log(this.signupForm)
    this.authService.signup({
      'email': this.signupForm.get('email').value,
      'username': this.signupForm.get('username').value,
      'name': this.signupForm.get('name').value,
      'password': this.signupForm.get('passwords.password').value
    })
    .subscribe(
      (data: AuthResData) => {
        this.isLoginMode = true;
        this.success='Signup was successful';
        this.error = null;
      },(errorRes)=>{
        console.log(errorRes);
      }
    )
  }
```

https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

I have found the documentation and tried implementing it myself but have had troubles understanding how to properly fix this error in my use case.

Answer (score 2):

https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

```
.subscribe({
   next: (data: AuthResData) => {
        this.isLoginMode = true;
        this.success='Signup was successful';
        this.error = null;
      },
   error: (errorRes) => {
        console.log(errorRes);
      }
   });
```